# Oracle form validate multiple previous row record in grid

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

> Technology : Oracle 10g forms, JDK 1.6, IE 8

I am trying to validate 2nd row record i.e.,'18/06/17' from date against 1st row record from and to date i.e., '16/06/17' & '20/06/17' as it shouldn't be between 1st record date.

What I need to do is show message/validation message before commit, when user enter record in either 2nd [from date/ to date], 3rd row's[from date/ to date] and so on.

I am having problem, Finding way to validate 2nd row from date Against previously entered 1st row fields of from-to date. validation message must be like 'date shouldn't be between '16/06/17' and '20/06/17'

Any link to article or example is appreciated.
PS: I already wasted 2 day on this problem.

[image: My oracle form 10g]

Comment: So which bit of your task is giving you a problem?

Comment: @APC, how to do validation before commit ? like we do in JavaScript in html with message alert.

Answer (score 1):

create two global variables at form startup and initialize at the time of first record entering as below:

-- determine if first record using record_number then initialize

```
If :global.fromdate is null then
-- means it is not yet initialize and will not let initialize after first record -- values initialization.
   :global.fromdate := :yourblock.fromdate;
   :global.todate := :yourblock.todate;
end if;
```

Then determine if not first record then check

```
if :yourblock.fromdate >= :global.fromdate and :yourblock.fromdate <= :global.todate then
   show_alert('youralert');
end if;
```